# Объекты и ссылки в php

Tags: php

Прочитал я мануал по данной теме, но не понял, читал я на php.net, там был следующий пример:

```
<?php
class A {
    public $foo = 1;
}  

$a = new A;
$b = $a;     // $a и $b копии одного идентификатора
             // ($a) = ($b) = <id>
$b->foo = 2;
echo $a->foo."\n";


$c = new A;
$d = &$c;    // $c и $d ссылки
             // ($c,$d) = <id>

$d->foo = 2;
echo $c->foo."\n";


$e = new A;

function foo($obj) {
    // ($obj) = ($e) = <id>
    $obj->foo = 2;
}

foo($e);
echo $e->foo."\n";

?>
```

Тут 3 примера и все они выводят число 2

Разницу я не увидел, кто хорошо понимает данный материал прошу разъяснить

P.S Хотелось бы четко понимать различие в этих 3ех примерах

Comment: Объекты _всегда_ передаются и присваиваются в PHP по ссылке. Именно поэтому результат каждого из примеров один и тот же.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А, в том то и дело, что разницы никакой нет. В PHP начиная с версии 5.3 все объекты передаются по ссылке, а значок `&` приводит к фатальной ошибке.

Возможно, Вы не понимаете саму суть ссылок? Попробуйте почитать вот эту статью на оф. сайте PHP: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.references.whatdo.php

Основное смысл применения ссылок - это экономия памяти, т.к. при обращении по ссылке не происходит создание копии объекта.

Comment: суть я понимаю и чтобы доказать я попробую объяснить как я это понимаю: допустим у нас есть объект с id = 108273, этот объект изначально имеет имя переменной допустим $first, чтобы не создавать новый id, мы можем сделать псевдоним переменной $first, допустим: $alt_first, при изменении свойств объекта значения будут меняться у обоих переменных так как они ссылаются на один и тот же id объекта

Comment: Ну, всё верно - у Вас есть переменная $first, в ней хранится объект, у которого в свойство id записано значение 108273. Если вы создаете переменную $alt_first = $first, и измените значение свойства id у любой из переменной, то значение поменяется у обеих. Точно также как и в примерах из Вашего поста. Разницы никакой нет.

Comment: хмм, понятно, а я думал что в этом есть разница, ну раз это все одно и тоже тогда, ок